# IF statement: TRUE/ FALSE when a condition is met/unmet when referring to cells on another Excel sheet AND a specific entry in a second column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-365

I have a sheet in my workbook called `Students_Record`. On that sheet, I am entering a formula that refers to columns of cells (`StudentNumber` and `LessonType`) from another sheet called `Class_Record`.

I want it it to look through the `ClassType` column for all rows that correspond with a given `StudentNumber` and see if there are any cells that contain a specific `ClassType`. (e.g. trial, VOC)  I want it to say TRUE if the condition is met and I want it to say FALSE if the condition is not met.

I have tried the following formula:

```
=IFS('Class_Record'!H2:H3392="1"(NOT('Class_Record'!L2:L3392="Trial",FALSE,TRUE)
```

But it says that too many arguments have been entered.

Comment: Something like `=COUNTIFS('Class_Record'!H2:H3392,1,'Class_Record'!L2:L3392,"Trial")>0`

Comment: @HayleyJonasson you may try this one as well, `=SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$3392=1)*($L$2:$L$3392="Trial"))>0`